# Option menu checkbox android

Tags: android

I have a problem with the option menu checkable item

[image]

I want the `checkbox` be placed right of `title` not under it.

He is my `option.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item android:id="@+id/notif"
        android:title="Notification"
        android:checkable = "true"/>
</group>
</menu>
```

Thanks.

Comment: I realy need help guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will only be the case in the menu preview in Android Studio.  On your device it will display as expected.

---

For example:

In Android Studio, mine looks like yours:

[image: Android Studio screenshot]

When I start the application and check, it looks like I expect:

[image: Emulator screenshot]

Hope this helped!